# Apache proxy all ws connections to different port

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, websocket

In my Apache 2.4 vhost I'm trying to get all `https://` traffic to carry on to port 443, but all `ws://` traffic to forward onto `ws://*:6969`.

Eg:

`https://example.com/index` would just go to `https://example.com/index:443` as normal.

`ws://example.com/anypathhere/` would be forwarded to `ws://example.com/anypathhere:6969`

So far I've tried the commented out values in the vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    RewriteOptions Inherit
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    DirectoryIndex disabled

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            RewriteEngine On
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}index.php [L]
    </Directory>

    ServerName localhost.localdomain


  #ProxyPreserveHost On
  #ProxyRequests Off
  #ProxyPassMatch / ws://192.16.4.177:6969/ retry=0
  #ProxyPassReverse ws:// ws://192.16.4.177:6969/
  #ProxyPass ws:// ws://192.16.4.177:6969/
  #RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteRule ws:// ws://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1:6969 [NC,R=301,L]
```

All of these result in

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://192.16.4.177:443
```

or a 400 error.

Answer (score 3):

You truly need to add a vhost for ws traffic which is listening on `*:80`

Theres is one point, which fail either with `RewriteCond` or with `ProxyPass` at the wrong VHost-File. 
Your traffic is encrypted by the certificate you're using. Therefore the Connection won't be established correctly. Your remote host can't read it.

Based on the documentation in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket):

> The communications are done over TCP port number 80 [..]

Your additional VHost-File should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost.localdomain
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPassReverse / ws://192.16.4.177:6969/
  ProxyPass / ws://192.16.4.177:6969/
</VirtualHost>
```

As explanation. All your request going over http:80 are redirected to ws:6969.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that would be to tell the client to use the right port... but if you want to proxy or redirect when they use the wrong port:

I don't know anything about ws://, but I believe you would need to use a `RewriteCond` for that, since a `RewriteRule` and similar don't contain the scheme to match. See the [directive reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). This will probably only work if ws:// requests look like HTTP requets, or you have a module that specially handles ws:// requests. (To use `RewriteCond`, you can list it as many times as you want, and it applies only to the next RewriteRule [or similar?])

eg. for proxying:

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} "^ws$"
RewriteRule "^(/?.*)$" ws://otherhost:6969/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way to do this. Peter's answer doesn't work because Websockets piggybacks over HTTP(S) as an GET request with [special headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2.1). Whatever logic `mod_rewrite` uses to detect the URL scheme isn't smart enough to detect this, so the scheme always shows up as `http` or `https`.

In theory, you could look for the headers yourself, with something like the following syntax:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} ^websocket$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ws://192.16.4.177:6969/$1 [proxy]
```

However, while this rule does match the opening client handshake (confirmed in my logs), this doesn't give me a working Websocket redirect. I suspect that `mod_rewrite` doesn't actually understand how to proxy Websocket connections, even if you can get the handshake to go to the right place.

That leaves us with JinnFox's answer. If you are able to move your Websockets endpoint to somewhere other than `/`, that might be an acceptable solution.

P.S. In the mean time, I have found that [NGINX handles this case nearly seamlessly](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) (scroll down to step 6 to find a code snippet that works for both HTTP and WS).